# VS Code - Unable to open file

Tags: php, git, github, visual-studio-code

I created a new file, this file exist in the folder structure, but when I try to open it I get this Unable to Open and create File message?

[image]

If I cancel the message and it says "Editor could not opened because the file was not found"

[image]

If I try to create a file using the message box link it gives me below error saying overwrite flag is not set

[image]

But I dont get this error if I create it in the root, only when creating in includes/classes which was created after cloning the project from git.

could this be a issue with git permissions?

Comment: It's not a *Git* permissions problem, but it probably is a *permissions* problem.

Answer (score 0):

It can happend only i one time , if u have commited this file on an another branch which is previous , and you now on another branch that don't have this file commited .
To clear your head of this problem open another folder and clone your repository inside, pull all your branches and stay up to date with your git tree .